# Is using a Master Table for shared columns good practice for an entire database?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, database-design, entity-attribute-value

Below, I explain a basic design for a database I am working on.  As I am not a DB, I am concerned if I am on a good track or a bad one so I wanted to float this on stack for some advice. I was not able to find a similar discussion that fit's my design.

In my database, every table is considered an entity.  An Entity could be a customer account, a person, a user, a set of employee information, contractor information, a truck, a plane, a product, a support ticket, etc etc.  Here are my current entities (Tables)...

- People
- Users
- Accounts
- AccountUsers
- Addresses
- Employee Information
- Contractor Information

And to store information about these Entities I have two tables:

```
Entity Tables
-EntityType
-> EntityTypeID (INT)
-Entities
-> EntityID (BIGINT)
-> EnitityType (INT) : foreign key
```

Every table I have made has an Auto Generated primary key, and a foreign key on an entityID column to the entities table.

In the entities table I have some shared fields like,

- DateCreated
- DateModified
- User_Created
- User_Modified
- IsDeleted
- CanUIDelete

I use triggers on all of the table's to automatically create their entity entry with the correct entity type on inserts.  And update triggers update the LastModified date.

From an application layer point of view, all the code has to do is worry about the individual entities (except for the USER_Modified/User_Created fields "it does updates on that" by joining on the entityID)

Now the reason for the entities table, is down the line I plan on having an EAV model, so every entity type can be extended with custom fields.  It also serves as a decent place to store metadata about the entities (like the created/modified fields).

I'm just new to DB design, and want a 2nd opinion.

Comment: 1. MySQL, SQL Server? Pick one.

2. "I plan on having an EAV model .... I'm just new to DB design" Obviously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I plan on having an EAV model, so every entity type can be extended with custom fields.

Why? Do *all* your entities require to be extensible in this way? Probably not -- in most applications there are one or two entities at most that would benefit from this level of flexibility. The other entities actually benefit from the stability and clarity of *not* changing all the time.

EAV is an example of the [Inner-Platform Effect](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/The_Inner-Platform_Effect.aspx):

> The Inner-Platform Effect is a result of designing a system to be so customizable that it ends becoming a poor replica of the platform it was designed with.

In other words, now it's your responsibility to write application code to do all the things that a proper RDBMS already provides, like constraints and data types. Even something as simple as making a column mandatory like `NOT NULL` doesn't work in EAV.

It's true sometimes a project requires a lot of tables. But you're fooling yourself if you think you have simplified the project by making just two tables. You will still have just as many distinct Entities as you would have had tables, but now it's up to you to keep them from turning into a pile of rubbish.

Before you invest too much time into EAV, read this story about a company that nearly ceased to function because someone tried to make their data repository arbitrarily flexible: [Bad CaRMa](https://www.simple-talk.com/opinion/opinion-pieces/bad-carma/).

I also wrote more about EAV in a blog post, [EAV FAIL](https://karwin.com/blog/index.php/2009/05/21/eav-fail/), and in a chapter of my book, [SQL Antipatterns Volume 1: Avoiding the Pitfalls of Database Programming](https://pragprog.com/titles/bksap1/sql-antipatterns-volume-1/).

Comment: Sorry I forgot all about this post and was a long time ago.  We switched to MS SQL 2014 because MySql's schema Editor saves in Binary.  Also I am using SSDT in VS 2015 now.  So I was able to build out the whole database with SSDT "full sql file based design" with contraints, stored procs, etc.  The data layer is PetaPoco and uses the T4 templates to automatically generate the pocos and data layer code.  I also used T4 templates to generate audit tables automatically.  And when we want to add fields etc we just update the Project and deploy the changes with SSDT and regenerate petapoco.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't really given a design. If you had given a description of tables, the application-oriented criterion for when a row goes in of each them and consequent constraints including keys, fks etc for the part of your application involving your entities then you would have given part of a design. In other words, if you had given that part's straightforward relational design. (Just because you're not implementing it that way doesn't mean you don't need to design properly.) Notice that this must include application-level state and functionality for "extending with custom fields". But then you have to give a description of tables, the criterion for when a row goes in each of them and consequent constraints including keys, fks etc for the part of your implementation that encodes the previous part via EAV, plus operators for manipulating them. In other words, if you had given that part's straightforward relational design. The part of your design that is [implementing a DBMS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23950836/3404097). Then you would really have given a design.

The notion that one needs to use EAV "so every entity type can be extended with custom fields" is mistaken. Just implement via calls that update metadata tables sometimes instead of just updating regular tables: DDL instead of DML.